# ODOO Installation on mac osx

Tags: odoo, osx-elcapitan

I have try of differents ways to install odoo 10 in my mac osx (10.11.6).
always receive the same error.
I did the instalation using a virtual env.
The installation ended fine, but I haven't be able to run it.
it seems a issue with db connection but where and how

```
(odoo-env)Nelsons-MacBook-Air:odoo nelsondiaz$ ./odoo-bin
2017-08-29 14:44:22,963 18435 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2017-08-29 14:44:22,963 18435 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/Users/nelsondiaz/Library/Application Support/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/addons', u'/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/addons']
2017-08-29 14:44:22,963 18435 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2017-08-29 14:44:22,978 18435 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
```

This is the error after running http://127.0.0.1:8069/ or http://localhost:8069/

I try updating pg_hba.conf and odoo.conf
nothing work, the same error

```
2017-08-29 14:50:25,948 18435 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
2017-08-29 14:50:25,952 18435 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2017 14:50:25] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -    
2017-08-29 14:50:25,965 18435 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 249, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
        result = handler(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1308, in __call__
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1282, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1446, in dispatch
        self.setup_db(httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1368, in setup_db
        httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1524, in db_monodb
        dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1498, in db_list
        dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 325, in list_dbs
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 635, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 177, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 518, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 586, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
    2017-08-29 14:50:26,238 18435 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed
    2017-08-29 14:50:26,242 18435 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2017 14:50:26] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    2017-08-29 14:50:26,249 18435 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 181, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 249, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 186, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 172, in application_unproxied
        result = handler(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1308, in __call__
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1282, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1446, in dispatch
        self.setup_db(httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1368, in setup_db
        httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1524, in db_monodb
        dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1498, in db_list
        dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 325, in list_dbs
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 635, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 177, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 518, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/nelsondiaz/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 586, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: It seems that the server is having problem when its trying to connect with the database **odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed**.  
Check your configuration file to see whether you have given the correct username and password for database connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't run the server without error only with the command ./odoo-bin
For any reason that I don't know it does not find the conf file.
That I did it was put the conf file in the parameter and it works:

option 1:

```
./odoo-bin --addons-path=/Users/myuser/Sites/odoo-env/odoo/addons -c debian/odoo.conf
```

Option 2

```
 ./odoo-bin -d odoo --db_user odoo --db_password odoo
```